# CSS background-image not showing

Tags: html, css, background-image

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css">

        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background-image: url(man_meteor.jpg);
                background-repeat: no-repeat;  
                background-size: cover;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                background-position: center;
            }
```

Why is my background img not showing?
Below is how my files are arranged.
[image]

Comment: NB: content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" change to content="text/html" charset=UTF-8".

Comment: Wait a minute, where is the html file you're calling it from?

Comment: Working fine for me

Comment: does the link to your stylesheet work? If no, it's clearly a filepath issue (i.e. both that and your missing background image). Which file contains the code you posted?

Comment: The code is from home.jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggest that your content is written inside a file called home.jsp, I suspect you are mapping "/" to one of your servlets which forwards your home.jsp to the client. This isn't right because this mapping will map every other resources to the same servlet that you use to forward your home.jsp. The correct mapping is to map "" instead.

One of your blocks in your web.xml should look like this instead:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>The name of your servlet that forwards home.jsp</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern></url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: OMG! you are a genius!

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your code i can say that you need to specify `height:200px OR height:400px` example and next just for safety add double quotes like `background-image: url("man_meteor.jpg");`. Try this their are else other ways to get around.